# Basic matrix calculus question

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I am struggling with a basic matrix calculus question.

Suppose you had $f(\textbf{x}) = (\textbf{a} - \textbf{Bx})^T(\textbf{a} - \textbf{Bx})$

where $\textbf{a}$ and $\textbf{B}$ are a vector and matrix of constants respectively. I am interested in finding the gradient of $f$ with respect to $\textbf{x}$. I would appreciate it if someone could write down the steps needed to compute this gradient.

I know that $d(\textbf{a} - \textbf{Bx})/d\textbf{x} = -\textbf{B}^T$, but I don't know how to apply the derivative operator to the product of $(\textbf{a} - \textbf{Bx})$ with itself.

EDIT: the gradient and the derivative are not the same thing. I am interested only in the gradient.

Comment: You could also try applying the product rule from regular single variable calculus

Answer (score 0):

Recall that transposing a scalar leaves it unchanged.

Then consider the scalar function 
$$\eqalign{
 f &= y^Tz \\
df &= dy^Tz + y^Tdz \quad &({\rm product\, rule}) \\
&= z^Tdy + y^Tdz \quad &({\rm transposed\, first\, term}) \\
}$$
Now set $z=y\,$ to obtain
$$\eqalign{
df &= 2y^Tdy \\
}$$
Now let $y=(Bx-a)\,$ and therefore $\,dy=B\,dx$
$$\eqalign{
df &= 2y^TB\,dx = (2B^Ty)^T\,dx \\
}$$
So the gradient is
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} &= (2B^Ty) = 2B^T(Bx-a) \\
}$$

Comment: In your second equation, why is $df = y^Tdz + z^Tdy$ true?

Comment: I have annotated the first few steps. Better?

Comment: Makes sense, thanks